# Cannot add node to cluster (elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, kibana, packetbeat

I'm trying to make the health of my cluster green. According to the following elasticsearch documentation: `When you add more nodes to a cluster, it automatically allocates replica shards. When all primary and replica shards are active, the cluster state changes to green.`

source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html

So I created 2 elasticsearch instances with the following configuration files:

```
# Config File 1
cluster.name : PL
node.name : "Node-1"
node.master : true
node.data : true
network.host : "127.0.0.1"
http.port : 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts : ["127.0.0.1:9200", "127.0.0.1:9201"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes : 2

# Config File 2
cluster.name : PL
node.name : "Node-2"
node.master : true
node.data : true
network.host : "127.0.0.1"
http.port : 9201
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts : ["127.0.0.1:9200", "127.0.0.1:9201"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes : 2
```

By running the following curl command : `curl -GETX localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true` I should according the elasticsearch documentation (see link below) have 2 nodes on my cluster. However, my number of nodes remains at 1.

source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_add_failover.html

Comment: Can you add the logs from each node when you start them?

Comment: Sure I'm kinda new to stack overflow so would you rather have me edit my post and put them or would it be better suited if I uploaded them and share the link with you?

Comment: If you can put them in your post, that's fine (should not be too long I guess) otherwise just gist them and provide the link.

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/GlamorCodius/58cb2d8e7e403d1c795fe12eaa9a43a7

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the port you're using in the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` setting is not the correct one, it should be the TCP port, not the HTTP one.

However, since you're running on ES7, a [new discovery protocol](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_discovery_changes) is now being used, which ignores the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` setting.

Since you're running both nodes on the same machine, you don't need any special configuration to have both nodes form a cluster, they should [auto-discover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html#_auto_bootstrapping_in_development_mode) themselves (provided you remove the `discovery.*` settings.

If you're running the two nodes on two different machines, then you need to use [the following settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/discovery-settings.html) instead:

```
discovery.seed_hosts:
   - 127.0.0.1:9300
   - 127.0.0.1:9301
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
   - 127.0.0.1:9300
   - 127.0.0.1:9301
```

Comment: I removed the `discovery.*` settings as you advised me. However, it didn't seem to work, the `curl` command kept showing me that the number of nodes is equal to 1. I therefore tried the other solution that you provided (even though I'm on the same machine) and the result didn't seem to change.

Comment: So After doing what you suggested, I had a warning telling me that replication was not possible due to the fact that `low disk watermark [??%] exceeded on`. I therefor corrected it with the following settings: `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: true
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage: 5gb
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low: 30gb
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high: 20gb` Now the error is gone but sadly the number of nodes on the cluster remains at 1.